# Add linkedlist to linkedlist in java

Tags: java

I have created two linked lists and I want to add the values from LinkedList1 into LinkeList2 for Example:

```
private LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
private LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
```

I used list1 in different class and i add too many values to it. What i want to do is move the values from list1 into list2 and clear the values from list1 and keep going. At the end I would like to come up with big list2.

Any help!

Answer (score 3):

LinkedList implements the [List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) from Java, therefore you can just invoke addAll from one list to the other.

```
list2.addAll(list1);  //append all elements in list1 to the end of list2
list1.clear();        //empty contents of list1
```

Comment: (Just being pedantic; `List` is an interface, not a class)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it may be, but given the scope of this question I just made a guess.

Comment: Whether or not something from the standard library is a class or interface is pretty googleable though...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
list2.addAll(list1);
```

Comment: BTW, If you are going to concatenate, it is better to use LinkedList than ArrayList instances. And it is better to use it via interface, i.e. 
    private List list1 = new LinkedList();

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan Can you expand on why it is better to initialize them as List objects if they inherit the methods from List interface anyways?

Comment: @mloewent, The main reason is to use **polymorphism**. I.e. if after time desided to use ArrayList instead LinkedList you will change the type only its method. Other methods which are using that method with List type parameter, will not be changed at all.

Comment: @mloewent, BTW you don't need to call `list1.clear();` because it will be cleared by `Garbage collector`, when you will exit from the scope when declared list1. It will be more effective.